# Is it possible to only use one color of an RGB LED strip?

Tags: lighting

I have been given some RGB rolls of led lighting. I only want to use the red or blue on a boat... can I cut it and only solder only 2 wires say to ground and R and get red, ground and B and get blue?

Comment: Assuming that the strip has 4 wires, ground, red, green and blue, then yes, you can use whichever wires, along with the ground, to produce the appropriate colors. On the other hand, many LED rolls have a built-in controller that must be connected to a microprocessor (or similar circuitry) ot active the LEDs. More information is required to tell what you have.

Comment: @DoxyLover Should posted as answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Doxylover is right.  most inexpensive RGB LED strips have four conductors; the three colors and ground.   The ones I've used can take variable voltage on each circuit to allow color mixing and dimming.

Are you looking to have variety in color?  or just a stripe of a color to accent?

I think your boat is going to look fantastic.   Nice lighting.

Comment: Expensive RGB LED strips also have four conductors: power, ground, data+, and data-.